# XPath Ancestors

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have an XML document that matches our site navigation something like this:

```
<page name="home" url="/" />
<page name="about" url="/about" />

<folder name="folder1">

    <page name="page1" url="folder1/page1" />
    <page name="page2" url="folder1/page2" />

    <folder name="folder2">

       <page name="page3" url="folder1/folder2/page3" />
       <page name="page4" url="folder1/folder2/page4" />

    <folder>

<folder>
```

I need an xpath statement that for a given page will return all the ancestor elements (folders).

e.g. (doesn't work) `ancestor::page[@name='page4']`

It should return the ancestors regardless of how deeply nested the folders are.

Comment: Please fix the title first, question has nothing to with `preg match`.

Comment: My bad - that was for a previous question I nearly asked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question this seems to work `//page[@name="page1"]/ancestor::*`